# Rails time difference between respond, views and activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When making an API call, I get the following:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1228ms (Views: 296.0ms | ActiveRecord: 76.9ms)
```

Why is there about a 800ms difference between ActiveRecord + Views and the 200 response? How do I find out where that time is being spent?

Comment: That time is probably on the server's end in relaying the response

Comment: @WesFoster how can I find out where the difference is coming from? Is it the `as_json` methods being too large... I am not sure :S

Comment: Watch server logs. It should show you the connection information. The overall process is Connection > Upload > Process (what Rails shows you) > Download > Display. Rails shows you what it does, the server should show you the rest.

Comment: @WesFoster forgive my ignorance. I am seeing the server logs from the `Started GET` to the `Completed 200 OK` surrounding the db queries. But I cam not sure how can I see the whole cycle?